# Layers function Blender 2.8 missing

Tags: layers

Where is the layers button/function that was in 2.79? I have not been able to find the layers function.

Answer (score 2):

Layers are now called "Collections". You can find them in the right sidebar.

Here you can find more informations: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/collections/collections.html